# Combine two rows with the same class using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my question.

```
   ## data for example
   Name    type        Value1      Value2     Value3            Value4             
    A     unemp  1.733275e+09  2.067889e+09  3.279421e+09  3.223396e+09   
    B     unemp  1.413758e+09  2.004171e+09  2.383106e+09  2.540857e+09   
    C     unemp  1.287548e+09  1.462072e+09  2.831217e+09  3.528558e+09   
    A     unemp  2.651480e+09  2.846055e+09  5.882084e+09  5.247459e+09   
    D     unemp  2.257016e+09  4.121532e+09  4.961291e+09  5.330930e+09   
    C     unemp  7.156784e+08  1.182770e+09  1.704251e+09  2.587171e+09   
    E      emp    6.012397e+09  9.692455e+09  2.288822e+10  3.215460e+10   
    F      emp    5.647393e+09  9.597211e+09  2.121828e+10  3.107219e+10   
    G      emp    4.617047e+09  8.030113e+09  2.005203e+10  2.755665e+10
```

My target: *Compare the "Name" column and combine rows with same "Name"*.

Using code below:

```
 f_test = pd.read_clipboard()
 f_test.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index()
```

[image]

The result shows like this.
But how to retain the "type" column? Wish someone's advice!

Comment: The problem here is that `type` is not a numeric column so it doesn't make sense to aggregate on this column which is why it's dropped, you'd have to add the type column back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the result with a column-subset of the original DataFrame:

```
>>> pd.merge(
    f_test.groupby('Name').sum().reset_index(),
    f_test[['Name', 'type']].drop_duplicates(),
    how='right')

    Name    Value1  Value2  Value3  Value4  type
0   A   4.384755e+09    4.913944e+09    9.161505e+09    8.470855e+09    unemp
1   B   1.413758e+09    2.004171e+09    2.383106e+09    2.540857e+09    unemp
2   C   2.003226e+09    2.644842e+09    4.535468e+09    6.115729e+09    unemp
3   D   2.257016e+09    4.121532e+09    4.961291e+09    5.330930e+09    unemp
4   E   6.012397e+09    9.692455e+09    2.288822e+10    3.215460e+10    emp
5   F   5.647393e+09    9.597211e+09    2.121828e+10    3.107219e+10    emp
6   G   4.617047e+09    8.030113e+09    2.005203e+10    2.755665e+10    emp
```